# iOS 8 beta - Location Manager Not Registering User Location

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location, ios8

Since the new iOS 8 beta release, I have not been able to successfully get a user's location. Prior to the update to iOS 8 I had no issues, but now it always returns 0.000000 as the current latitude and longitude. Is this just a bug in the new release? My code is listed below:

```
//from the .h file
@interface MasterViewController : PFQueryTableViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate> {

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

//from the .m file
@synthesize locationManager = _locationManager;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager {
   if (_locationManager != nil) {
       return _locationManager;
   }

   _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   _locationManager.delegate = self;
   _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

   return _locationManager;
}

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation { 
}

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
                    didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
}
```

**UPDATE**
This question has been answered ([Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)). For anyone still struggling with this, to maintain backwards compatibility with iOS 7, I used the code below:

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])    { }
```

Comment: I fixed the issue,the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working

Comment: I found the solution here
http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-fix-cllocationmanager-location.html

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your update/comment, iOS8 requires you to use `requestAlwaysAuthorization` or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` as well as a new `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` key in `Info.plist`

**But there is something else which is wrong in your code:**

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
        didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

It has been deprecated in iOS6 and you should now use this new delegate method instead:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
```

You can then get the latest location with something like this:

```
CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
```

Comment: I got solution from here
http://datacalculation.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-fix-cllocationmanager-location.html