# iOS 8 and iBeacon - kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, ios8

I have been working with iBeacons for the last few months. I have just recently updated to iOS8 Beta 1 and have found that region monitoring and ranging no longer works on my beacon apps.

It is being caused by permissions. I now get a `kCLErrorRegionMonitoringDenied` error returned when attempting to start region monitoring. This error corresponds to a user deselecting the location permissions for the app.

If I go into **Settings>Privacy>Location Services** I get some weird behaviour. Sometimes my app appears on this list with no setting chosen, and other times it doesn't appear on the list at all. If I manually change the setting to 'Allow' and then close Settings, then go back to **Settings>Privacy>Location Services** I have the same problem - the app might not appear on the list or the settings are not set.

This is obviously a bug in iOS8 beta, just wondering if anyone else has this problem and/or found a workaround?

Comment: It may be related to this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For iBeacons in iOS8, you must use requestAlwaysAuthorization, *not* requestWhenInUseAuthorization

(via: http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/)

Comment: That was it! Thanks. I assume that for testing WhenInUse authorization is enough. I was wrong. For monitoring, authorization always is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the issue is, but I was having the same problem, I found that going back to Xcode before the beta solved my issue. I wish I could give a better answer than that, but I guess the problem might be somewhere in Xcode and not ios 8.

I actually did more research into this and it seems ios 8 requires some authorization setup before trying to use location services. [This might help answer your question further.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working) Here are some links to direct documentation that you might find useful.[check out the requestWhenInUseAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization) [documentation on info plist key](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW18) This should help keep you in Xcode 6 with ios 8. sorry if I wasn't more helpful I'm fairly new to ios development.