# IOS8 LocationServices, permission reverts to neither allowed or disallowed. doesn't update location

Tags: location, ios8

I am running IOS8 on this device.

I'm using location services for an ios app.  It has worked well for a long time, however recent I am no longer receiving location updates.

One thing I checked is in Settings->Privacy->Location Services, whether it was enabled for the app.  Oddly, while all other apps were set to Always, or Never, my app was the only one with a blank value.  Neither was set.  After I choose Always, and run the app, it doesn't help.  When coming back to settings it is once again blank.

Interestingly, the same code works fine on my other IOS7 device, with location updates okay.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 : Location Services not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

A few additional settings are needed for IOS8 location services to work out of the box.  It is described here well.  This solved it.

[Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)