# Can't detect iBeacon in iOS 8

Tags: ios, ibeacon, ios8, estimote

I've followed online tutorials from [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-programming-ibeacons-tutorial/) and [Devfright](http://www.devfright.com/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-7-clbeaconregion-clbeacon/) to create an iBeacon detection app. I'm using an iBeacon from estimote, an iPad 3 with iOS 8. The app simply does not detect my iBeacon whereas its being detected by other iBeacon apps. I can't understand what I'm missing or doing wrong in my code.

Here's my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) CLBeaconRegion   *beaconRegion;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locManager;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *label2;

@end
```

Here's my .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locManager.delegate = self;

//default uuid for estimote beacons
NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"];

self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc]initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"com.rk.testregion"];

[self.locManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
[self locationManager:self.locManager didStartMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];

// Check if beacon monitoring is available for this device
if (![CLLocationManager isMonitoringAvailableForClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Monitoring not available" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil]; [alert show]; return;
}

}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray*)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion*)region
{
// Beacon found!
self.label1.text = @"Welcome to";
self.label2.text = @"Location 1";

CLBeacon *foundBeacon = [beacons firstObject];

// retrieve the beacon data from its properties
NSString *uuid = foundBeacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString;
NSString *major = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.major];
NSString *minor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", foundBeacon.minor];

NSLog(@"UUID: %@", uuid);
NSLog(@"major: %@", major);
NSLog(@"minor: %@", minor);

}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[self.locManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
[self.locManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion*)region
{
[self.locManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
self.label1.text = @"Searching again...";
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {

[self.locManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

@end
```

The delegate method didRangeBeacons simply does not get called. Could someone please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: Implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` `locationManager:didFailWithError:` and see if that gets called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out the answer below, which describes some extra hoops you now need to jump through to get this working:

[Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)

Full disclosure:  I have not tried this myself.

Comment: This works. Proof: I added a link to my Swift triangulation code on Github as well.