# Swift - Add MKAnnotationView To MKMapView

Tags: mkmapview, swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I'm trying to add `MKAnnotationView` to `MKMapView` but I can't do it… Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
    var homeLati: CLLocationDegrees = 40.01540192
    var homeLong: CLLocationDegrees = 20.87901079
    var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var longDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
    var theSpan:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, longDelta)
    var myHome:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(homeLati, homeLong)
    var myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    var theRegion:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, theSpan)
    self.theMapView.setRegion(theRegion, animated: true)
    self.theMapView.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
    self.theMapView.showsUserLocation = true
    ///Red Pin
    var myHomePin = MKPointAnnotation()
    myHomePin.coordinate = myHome
    myHomePin.title = "Home"
    myHomePin.subtitle = "Bogdan's home"
    self.theMapView.addAnnotation(myHomePin)

    var anView:MKAnnotationView = MKAnnotationView()
    anView.annotation = myHomePin
    anView.image = UIImage(named:"xaxas")
    anView.canShowCallout = true
    anView.enabled = true
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523702/stuck-on-using-mkpinannotationview-within-swift-and-mapkit/24532551#24532551 for an example using MKPinAnnotationView.  You can easily change it to a plain MKAnnotationView and set the image.  You don't need a custom annotation class for your purposes (MKPointAnnotation is fine).

Comment: Also note you should not try to access locationManager.location immediately after calling startUpdatingLocation.  It may not be ready yet.  Use the didUpdateLocations delegate method.  You also need to call requestAlwaysAuthorization/requestWhenInUseAuthorization (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working).

Comment: @Anna It works but I can't set the image I tryed with `pinView!.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "xaxas")` and `pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "xaxas")` added in Images.xcassets but unsuccessfully...

Comment: `UIImage(named:"xaxas")` should work and make sure the spelling is _exactly_ right including upper/lower case.  Try putting the image with the other project files instead of Images.xcassets.  It's also important to create a plain MKAnnotationView instead of MKPinAnnotationView when using custom images.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to implement the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method and return an `MKAnnotationView` from there.

Here's an example:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        //if annotation is not an MKPointAnnotation (eg. MKUserLocation),
        //return nil so map draws default view for it (eg. blue dot)...
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "test"

    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView.image = UIImage(named:"xaxas")
        anView.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        //we are re-using a view, update its annotation reference...
        anView.annotation = annotation
    }

    return anView
}
```

Remember you need to create a *plain* `MKAnnotationView` when you want to use your own custom image.  The `MKPinAnnotationView` should only be used for the standard pin annotations.

Also note you should not try to access `locationManager.location` immediately after calling `startUpdatingLocation`. It may not be ready yet.

Use the `didUpdateLocations` delegate method.

You also need to call `requestAlwaysAuthorization`/`requestWhenInUseAuthorization` (see [Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)).

Comment: Remove `!` exclamation mark from line - `if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation)`. Otherwise it will return `nil` for custom annotation instead of `MKPointAnnotation`.

Comment: @Kampai, What I would suggest instead is to say `if (annotation is MKUserLocation)` so it only returns `nil` for the map view's user location annotation.

Comment: Yes that is right, other wise `MKPointAnnotation` other than user location also not visible.

Comment: No, it's not that it isn't visible.  Returning nil tells the map view to return the default view for the annotation.  For MKUserLocation, it's a blue dot.  For anything else, it's a red pin.  It would be invisible if you return a non-nil MKAnnotationView with no image set.

Comment: Added missing curly bracket back (thanks to @DaniA for pointing this out).

Answer (score 1):

You have to show annotation, then you have to add the show annotation method:

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
mapVew.showAnnotations([annotation], animated: true)
```

`annotation` is an instance of `MKPointAnnotation`.

Answer (score 0):

1- your map view should delegate itself to your view controller 
2- you should implement

```
func mapView(aMapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: CustomMapPinAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!
```

this function is called from every annotation added to your Map

3- subclass your annotations to identify them in the viewForAnnotation method

4- in viewForAnnotation, add

```
if annotation.isKindOfClass(CustomMapPinAnnotation)
{
  // change the image here
var pinView = aMapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? YourSubclassedAnnotation
  pinView!.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: "xyz")
}
```

Comment: I get an error "Use of undeclared type CustomMapPinAnnotation"

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov if you want to use CustomMapPinAnnotation, you must create your own class.

Comment: i need pins dropped with animation , no matter it is custom or default.