# How change MKPointAnnotation image

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkpointannotation

I want to change  MKPointAnnotation image but I cant

this is my code .

```
let drowPin = MKPointAnnotation()
            drowPin.title = pin.company
            drowPin.subtitle = pin.Description
            drowPin.coordinate = annotation
            mapView.addAnnotation(drowPin)
```

Comment: @Timothy  MKPointAnnotation()has no  property called image

Comment: add the following delegate [method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32407096/4003548) in your class.