# MKMapViewAnnotation Image from custom image different for many pins

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I am trying to create many pins from a database of locations, each with custom images. The images are passed from the server in base64 format, I am able to create a `UIImage` from the base64 data, but I cannot upload the image as the icon instead of the pin for each annotation.

Any ideas how I can do this?

I tried to follow these SO posts to help, but they can only create a preset one, I can't figure out how edit all of them so they each have a unique icon:

[SO link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523702/stuck-on-using-mkpinannotationview-within-swift-and-mapkit) and [SO link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467408/swift-add-mkannotationview-to-mkmapview)

Any ideas?

here is my code to create the pins/annotations incase anyone is interested:

```
func mapTheseCoordinates(lat: Double, lng: Double, username: NSString, fullname: NSString) {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: lat,
        longitude: lng
    )
    // 2
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.15, 0.15)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    //3
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.setCoordinate(location)
    annotation.title = username
    annotation.subtitle = fullname
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631410/swift-different-images-for-annotation.

Comment: @Anna The pins are not showing up when I apply your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this Delegate event of mkmapview, here you can change different images as per your annotation

```
-(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *MyPin=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"current"];
    //MyPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    MyPin.highlighted = NO;
    MyPin.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_red"];

    return MyPin;
}
```

this delegate event will be called everytime you add anotation, but dont forget to set delegate for mapview

```
[mapLocation addAnnotation:annotObj];
```

Comment: How can I do this in swift? I did tag the post as swift, and provided swift code, I don't know Objective C well.

Comment: I don't know swift but I guess it should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631410/swift-different-images-for-annotation