# Attempting to change MKAnnotation color within my code?

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit, xcode6.3

So I have set up my `MKAnnotations` in MapView and it's working as I want it to. Now I would like to experiment further and try to change the colors of the pins, what would be the most efficient way to implement this within the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
var annotationQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")
currentLoc = PFGeoPoint(location: MapViewLocationManager.location)
//annotationQuery.whereKey("Location", nearGeoPoint: currentLoc, withinMiles: 10)
annotationQuery.whereKeyExists("Location")
annotationQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (points, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        // The find succeeded.
        println("Successful query for annotations")
        // Do something with the found objects

        let myPosts = points as! [PFObject]

        for post in myPosts {
            let point = post["Location"] as! PFGeoPoint
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude)
            annotation.title = post["title"] as! String!
            annotation.subtitle = post["username"] as! String!

            func mapView(aMapView: MKMapView!,
                    viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

                        let reuseId = "pin"
                        var pinView = aMapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView

                            println("Pinview was nil")
                            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
                            pinView!.animatesDrop = true
                            pinView!.pinColor = .Green
                        return pinView
                }


            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

    } else {
        // Log details of the failure
        println("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

I can't seem to tackle this on my own even though it seem's simple enough. I am also confused about the `viewForAnnotation` method, from what I could gather it seems like i need to use it, but nothing i'm trying is working.

Comment: Show the viewForAnnotation code that you tried.  Did you confirm that the delegate method was actually getting called (with a breakpoint or NSLog)?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24523702/stuck-on-using-mkpinannotationview-within-swift-and-mapkit for a simple example.  Remember to set/connect the map view's delegate outlet.

Comment: updated the code above with the viewForAnnotation method. The NSLog is not getting called.

Comment: The viewForAnnotation method must be outside other methods -- at the top level of the class (same as viewDidAppear).  Also, the first parameter may have to be "mapView" not "aMapView".

Comment: So this allows the pin colors to change, but I'm running into 2 issues. First, My blue current location beacon is no longer appearing and instead my current location is replaced with a pin and follows my current location around. Secondly, i set the callout to true but don't get an option to segue to a new view when the annotation title/subtitle are tapped. Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a late answer but for anyone else searching, check out the tutorial here which shows exactly how to colour pins

[Ray Wenderlich MapView](https://www.raywenderlich.com/160517/mapkit-tutorial-getting-started)