# Drop annotation pins with animation swift2.0

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, swift2, mapkit

I want to drop annotation pins on a mapView with animation. I have tried with below code but it is not working.

```
anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView!.canShowCallout = true
            anView!.animatesDrop = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you want to set the `anView!.image = UIImage(named:"your-image")` if you are using an MKAnnotationView.

If you are looking to just use the standard pin similar to apple maps, then you will want to use `MKPinAnnotationView`

Otherwise you may want to check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467408/swift-add-mkannotationview-to-mkmapview?answertab=active#tab-top)

You will also want to make sure that you are initialising and returning the view from within this delegate method.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView!
```

Comment: i need pin dropped with animation.

Comment: To do custom animations, check out this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857160/how-can-i-create-a-custom-pin-drop-animation-using-mkannotationview/2087253#2087253)