# Cannot get user's location with NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Tags: cllocationmanager, ios8, xcode6

I'm using Xcode 6 beta (6A215l). I've referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working) and updated my code to:

- use `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in the .plist file,
- call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` in the source code

but neither `didUpdateLocations:` nor `didFailWithError:` was called. If I use `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `requestAlwaysAuthorization`, my app works.

Does anyone have the same problem? I wonder if I should try with Xcode 6 beta 2..

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 : Location Services not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)

Comment: @killswitch : I read that question already before posting my question

Answer (score 2):

In fact, if you want to use the requestWhenInUseAuthorization in your app and gets the `didUpdateLocations:` and `didFailWithError:` delegate methods to be called, you need to set in your .plist file **BOTH** `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` keys, to make it work. 
Theses texts will then be displayed in the *Settings/Privacy/Location Services/App* section of your device.