# MapKit giving wrong lat & lang - iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios8, mapkit, cllocationmanager, cllocation

When I try to use map in iOS 8, I get below error.

```
Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

[For this I tried solution from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working), but still no luck.

Below is what I did.

### Step 1. Have entry in Info.plist

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription - This is test text
```

### Step 2. Updated -(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    // this is change
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

    return coordinate;
}
```

### Step 3. Prefix.pch

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
```

### Step 4. Delete the app again with below in viewDidLoad.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
theCoordinate = [self getLocation];

NSLog(@"ffffff===%f===%f", theCoordinate.latitude, theCoordinate.longitude);
```

Still I get output as

```
ffffff===0.000===0.000
```

### Note:

I get warning, but that is just for half seconds and disappears and then I get message as

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate;
theCoordinate = [self getLocation];

NSLog(@"ffffff===%f===%f", theCoordinate.latitude, theCoordinate.longitude);
```

When I go in setting to check the status for Location, below is what I have.

[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

### I am testing on iPad 2 iOS 8.0 & simulator iOS 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was real problem, but putting below code in `viewDidLoad` solve problem.

```
mapView.delegate = self;
locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
     // Use one or the other, not both. Depending on what you put in info.plist
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
#endif
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24718342/1066828)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the CLLocationManager Delegate ( -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations ) to get location updates.

Here's a code snippet for your reference:

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
     CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations lastObject];

     NSLog(@"ffffff===%f===%f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Alternatively, you can implement the Mapkit's following delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKUserLocation *myLocation = userLocation;
    NSLog(@"ffffff===%f===%f", myLocation.coordinate.latitude, myLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Comment: did that too.. still its same.... I found the solution, will post as answer now...

Answer (score 0):

The `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` runs asynchronously, so you should not be calling `startUpdatingLocation` until you get a change in authorization status in your delegate.