# Iphone 5s iOS 8.1.2 View Controller Loading Map from XIB, crashes

Tags: iphone, ios8, mkmapview

We are seeing this on ONLY iPhone 5s with iOS 8.1.2.  Other devices with 8.1.2 seem to be working fine.

The view controller that has a Map loading from an XIB is init fine, but when tries to load we get...  Will be trying some things to try and get around this, but any help would be appreciated.

```
2014-12-16 16:03:24.333 App[6140:995503] Stylesheet does not include style matching tree, or includes an old version.  Perhaps it was compiled by an old version of the style compiler.
2014-12-16 16:03:24.333 App[6140:995503] Please create a radar about this! (Check it's not a dup of rdar://16346611 first though)
2014-12-16 16:03:24.334 App[6140:995503] Active tile set: GEOActiveTileSet
App(6140,0x196aa8310) malloc: *** error for object 0x174206030: Invalid pointer dequeued from free list
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

With a large stack

```
#0  0x0000000191fa13f0 in __cxa_throw ()
#1  0x00000001927a0204 in objc_exception_throw ()
#2  0x0000000181f7b62c in -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] ()
#3  0x000000018f1e4318 in md::StyleMatchingTree::buildSubTrees(std::__1::set<int, std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<int> >&, std::__1::function<md::StyleMatchingTree* ()>&, NSArray*) ()
#4  0x000000018f28076c in __91-[VKStylesheet initWithData:miniData:forName:scale:ppi:vendor:targetDisplay:isDevResource:]_block_invoke ()
#5  0x0000000100a1ce30 in _dispatch_call_block_and_release ()
#6  0x0000000100a1cdf0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#7  0x0000000100a27854 in _dispatch_queue_drain ()
#8  0x0000000100a20120 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()
#9  0x0000000100a2975c in _dispatch_root_queue_drain ()
#10 0x0000000100a2af18 in _dispatch_worker_thread3 ()
#11 0x0000000192fc12e4 in _pthread_wqthread ()
Enqueued from Stylesheet Map Editing Queue (Thread 1)Queue : Stylesheet Map Editing Queue (serial)
#0  0x0000000100a2adac in _dispatch_barrier_async_f_slow ()
#1  0x000000018f27f458 in -[VKStylesheet initWithData:miniData:forName:scale:ppi:vendor:targetDisplay:isDevResource:] ()
#2  0x000000018f27ef20 in -[VKStylesheet initWithName:scale:ppi:targetDisplay:vendor:resourceManager:] ()
#3  0x000000018f2cd56c in __65-[VKStylesheetVendor stylesheetWithName:scale:ppi:targetDisplay:]_block_invoke ()
#4  0x0000000100a1cdf0 in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#5  0x0000000100a268c8 in _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke ()
#6  0x000000018f2cd43c in -[VKStylesheetVendor stylesheetWithName:scale:ppi:targetDisplay:] ()
#7  0x000000018f25b5d4 in -[VKStyleManager initWithName:scale:ppi:targetDisplay:sharedResources:] ()
#8  0x000000018f207984 in -[VKMapModel _setStyleManagerFromMapType:] ()
#9  0x000000018f1581d4 in -[VKMapModel forceMapType:] ()
#10 0x000000018f209188 in -[VKMapModel initShouldRasterize:mapPurpose:tileGroupIdentifier:locale:contentScale:] ()
#11 0x000000018f1fb4dc in -[VKMapCanvas initShouldRasterize:contentScale:target:device:inBackground:locale:] ()
#12 0x000000018f14ba6c in -[VKMapView initWithGlobe:shouldRasterize:inBackground:] ()
#13 0x00000001840e9f74 in -[MKBasicMapView initWithFrame:andGlobe:shouldRasterize:] ()
#14 0x000000018411dfcc in -[MKMapView _commonInitFromIB:gestureRecognizerHostView:showsAttribution:] ()
#15 0x000000018411ec3c in -[MKMapView initWithCoder:] ()
#16 0x0000000186d2cd98 in UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue ()
#17 0x0000000186d2ca54 in -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] ()
#18 0x0000000186c541bc in -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] ()
#19 0x0000000186d2cd98 in UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue ()
#20 0x0000000186d2cd38 in UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue ()
#21 0x0000000186d2ca54 in -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] ()
#22 0x0000000186c53644 in -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] ()
#23 0x0000000186b58274 in -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] ()
#24 0x0000000186848844 in -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] ()
#25 0x00000001868fdfb4 in -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] ()
#26 0x00000001868fdeb0 in -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] ()
#27 0x00000001868fd34c in -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] ()
#28 0x00000001868fcff8 in -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] ()
#29 0x00000001868fcd18 in -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] ()
#30 0x00000001868fcc98 in -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] ()
#31 0x0000000186845648 in -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] ()
#32 0x000000018619d994 in -[CALayer layoutSublayers] ()
#33 0x0000000186198564 in CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#34 0x0000000186198408 in CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) ()
#35 0x0000000186197c08 in CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) ()
#36 0x000000018619798c in CA::Transaction::commit() ()
#37 0x000000018683c61c in _afterCACommitHandler ()
#38 0x000000018204ea50 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ ()
#39 0x000000018204b9dc in __CFRunLoopDoObservers ()
#40 0x000000018204bdbc in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#41 0x0000000181f790a4 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#42 0x000000018b1235a4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#43 0x00000001868ae3c0 in UIApplicationMain ()
#44 0x0000000100144e64 in main at /Usersxxxx/main.m:17
#45 0x0000000192e0ea08 in start ()
```

[ADDITION]

With XCode 6.1.1 (don't think this matters, but might) with this small program (sample single view) exhibits the same issue on the 5s.  It's really the init that does it.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  testingmap
//
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) MKMapView *mapView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview: self.mapView];
}
```

Comment: Turns out that this might be a one off problem.  Phone had to have the "ALL DATA RESET" and then all is working fine.  Even the provided iOS MAPS application was not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, my iPhone was the phone in question and everything got fixed by just resetting all settings. 
Settings-> General-> Reset-> Reset All Settings.

Comment: Um, this person works with me and this DID solve the problem.

Comment: @VojtechVrbka Did you got the same issue? Is there another solution ? In my case I have a similar crash got by crash reporter, but I don't know if I can fix it.

Answer (score -2):

i hope it.this links useful for you. taking a time for getting map data. so you will put in view did appear and at the same time are you use xcode 6.0 and above version. [ios 8 and above version. can you use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717547/ios-8-map-kit-obj-c-cannot-get-users-location)
[It is Step For Map Data getting above ios 8.0 version](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/)