# Xcode user location no longer working in newer version (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, mkmapview

I have a button which moves to the user's location. I declare it in ViewControler.h and then added the following code into ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)userLocation:(id)sender {   
    [_mapView setCenterCoordinate:_mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
}
```

This keeps leading me to the (0,0) coordinates. Is there something in the newer Xcode version that I need to add to make this work again?

Comment: can you log the value of `_mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate`?

Comment: You should also make sure you actually have location services enabled. iOS 8 changed the way the permissions work for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since iOS8 you have to set a usage description for location services: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24718342/4948826