# Location Service in UIWebView on iOS8 beta 5 not working

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiwebview, ios8

Yesterday we tried the developer previews iOS 8 beta 5 with Xcode 6 Beta 5 for our App. 
We use location services in the webview components of our hybrid app.

I recognized that geolocating via UIWebView ist not working anymore. 
I verified this behavior with an example from scratch loading [example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation) for geolocation from the w3schools.com into a UIWebView.

With iOS 7, (Base SDK 7.1, built with XCode 5), the notification for acceptance of the location service is prompted an after that, the app shows up under Privacy--> Location Services in the iPhone settings. 
With iOS 8, (Base SDK 8, built with XCode 6) the prompt doesn't occur and the webview location service is not working and no entry in the settings is made.

I know, that with iOS 8 some changes took place for the users privacy settings especially dealing with location services in background, but I didn't expect that it will break our webview-location logic where we make use of the navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition) javascript function.

Anyway I am still not clear if this is a bug in iOS 8 beta or the result of some API changes and if, what would be the right way to adopt.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you add the new entries to your Info.plist? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working?rq=1

Comment: Yes I set the keys -- again -- and now it works -- maybe because the first time I didnt delete and reinstall the app. 
Just running the app from XCode after changing the plist file did not work. thx

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem on ios 8.3.

I solved the problem by adding *NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription* IN *Custom iOS Target Properties*.
[image]
[image]
It is this website that helped me: http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/working-easily-location-ios8-swift-oneshotlocationmanager/