# html 5 geolocation in UIWebview iOS 9

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've been unable to find a solution to this, on my website I'm loading in a Webview I have the following javascript function that is run after the page finishes loading:

```
var latitude, longitude, accuracy;

function setGeolocation() {
    accuracy = 5000;
    var geolocation = window.navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( 
        function ( position ) {
            if (position.coords.accuracy < accuracy){
                latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;

                loc = latitude + "," + longitude;
           }
            if (accuracy < 50) window.navigator.geolocation.clearWatch( geolocation );
        },
        function () { /*error*/ }, {
            maximumAge: 250, 
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        } 
    );

    window.setTimeout( function () {
            window.navigator.geolocation.clearWatch( geolocation );
        }, 5000 //stop checking after 5 seconds
    );
};
```

I've added the following to my Plist file:

- Privacy - Location Usage Description
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

And imported CoreLocation.Framwork

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this issue, I found the solution from the second comment on this question: [Location Service in UIWebView on iOS8 beta 5 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176750/location-service-in-uiwebview-on-ios8-beta-5-not-working)

Simply: **Uninstall the app and re-install it using XCode** then BOOM works fine.