# SKMaps follower user position Offline mode iOS 8 beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, offline-mode, skmaps

I have a problem with offline map on iOS 8.

SKMapFollowerModePositionPlusHeading works on strange way, it shows user position about Africa, although I am in Kiev (Ukraine).

On iOS 7 it's working good, there are only problems with iOS 8 last beta:

```
(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

self.skMapView.mapView.settings.followerMode = SKMapFollowerModePositionPlusHeading;
self.skMapView.mapView.settings.showCurrentPosition = YES;

}
```

Comment: This issue has been sent internally and it's pending with the development team

Comment: The fix is in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working
But as long as Skobbler is pre-compiled developer cannot address this issue in their code.

Answer (score 2):

The cause for this is that the current position is displayed at ( 0, 0 - near Africa) if the SDK doesn't receive valid GPS positions (this will be improved and it will not show any current position if none received)

There are two ways to avoid this issue:

- in case you're using the iPhone simulator: check if you've started the positions simulations;
- in case you're using a real device: check if location is enabled and permitted for the application.

Comment: Everything is enabled. Even more. The simulator location services are enabled and simulate my .gpx route. Still 0, 0 location is displayed on map.

Comment: It seems it's a bug, in the next version 2.3 will be fixed. As a workaround until then: go to Settings->Privacy->Location Services-> YourApp and change the setting to "Always". Let me know if it's working this way