# app using CLLocationManager and built against ios7 will work on ios8?

Tags: ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager

I understood that in ios8 CLLocationManager should first ask the users for new specific permissions ([Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working/24063578#24063578))

But if an app using CLLocationManager was built against ios7 (and working properly on ios7 and submitted in the store), will this app work on a ios8 device?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes apps built with iOS 7 SDK using Xcode 5 will work with iOS 8. My apps on Appstore works fine with iOS 8 beta 5. My dev builds created by Xcode 5 also work fine with iOS 8 beta (distributed using TestFlight).

Answer (score -1):

I have app that is currently on store that uses CLLocationManager and was built for iOS7. It works fine when installed on iOS8 device. But, i have a problem with new version of the app. I made some new features, didn't touch anything related to CLLocationManager, and when I build that new version with iOS7 SDK locations don't work on iOS8 device, while it still works fine on iOS7 devices.

Is there something special that I have to set up in the environment to make it work?