# Google map sdk for IOS 8 does not update location

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I'm running on IOS8 simulator and counter this problem: 
 `GMSMapView` is able to load map but it didn't ask for Location's permission, thus it could not update current user's location. (I did set a custom location, using GPX file)

However, `GMSMapView` still works fine on IOS 7.1, 7.0 ... 
My code is simple, init `mapView`, add it to controller's view and using KVO `myLocation` to observer location's change.

What should I do now ?

Comment: Update your SDK to latest version may be? as there are some changes regarding CLLocation in iOS 8 like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844430/xcode-6-gm-cllocationmanager/25844674#25844674

Comment: Check on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Google Maps SDK v1.8.1** doesn't request the location authorization that is needed in **iOS8**, so you need to do this in your application.

Use the `CLLocationManager`'s `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` method, and in the authorization changed delegate, enable location updates in the map view when authorization can be given.

Also, don't forget to add the correct keys in the `info.plist` to explain to your users why you need their location, as without this the call to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` don't do anything.