# CLLocationCoordinate2D latitude & longitude always zero

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationcoordinate2d

I am trying to get latitude & longitude. I am running following code on actual device but I always get zero for latitude & longitude. I also import library and set delegate also. May I know what is wrong and how to do? My device has ios 8.

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

if ([locationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}


CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" latitude:%f longitude:%f",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: Are delegate methods being called? you need to make some changes for iOS 8 as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844430/xcode-6-gm-cllocationmanager/25844674#25844674

Comment: did you set debug to a location?

Comment: How to set debug to location? @noobsmcgoobs

Comment: My delegate are not called. I have put both NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in my plist. When I call location, my app prompt user alert to allow or not. However, b4 I click, it automatically close. @Bhumit

Comment: before startUpatingLocation put this:  if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];    }

Comment: 2) try to make locationManager a “Property": @property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

Comment: Thanks you all. now it is working. I need to call this two method and also set up as described by @Bhumit
            [[AppDelegate instance].locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
            [[AppDelegate instance].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

Comment: Also beware, the simulator is buggy and gives random lat and long at times. I suspect this has something to do with the new OSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to get the current location in delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: delegate is not called. May I know how I shall do?

Comment: hope this helps: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/get-current-location-with-core-location