# Find My Location using mapview - iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, dictionary, mkmapview

I am trying to make a button that will locate my current location and zoom in. I did try the program and the error show up. Here is the program.

viewController.m

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;
}

-(IBAction)findmylocation:(id)sender;
```

viewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)findmylocation:(id)sender {

mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
mapview.delegate = self;  <-------[WARNING]
[mapview setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollow animated:YES];

}
```

The warning error show up on "mapview.delegate = self;" and when i run the application I can't click the button to locate my self. If i click it it will say

```
.... Application Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. 
Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

This is what warning said on "mapview.delegate = self;" line

```
Assigning to 'id<MKMapViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const_strong'
```

I don't know what is wrong?

Comment: Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] this is what you have to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 GM - CLLocationManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25844430/xcode-6-gm-cllocationmanager)

Comment: You get the warning when assigning your delegate because your Viewacontroller class definition doesn't include the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol.