# iOS 8 Mapview Current Location not fire

Tags: objective-c, iphone, mkmapview

`MKMapview` current user location not fire in `iOS-8`,previous `iOS-7` & `iOS-6` are working fine.

```
     self.mapView.delegate = self;
     self.mapView.showsUserLocation =YES;
```

In this line to call automatically the user current location delegate methods

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations{
}
```

but it not fire in `iOS-8`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 : Location Services not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)

Answer (score 6):

In iOS8, you need to request user's authorization before getting their location.

There are two kinds of request:

`-[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` lets you get users' location only when the app is awaken.

`-[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` lets you get users' location even when it's in the background.

You can choose between them accordingly.

For example, put this before you start updating location:

```
// ask for authorization
CLLocationManager * locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
// check before requesting, otherwise it might crash in older version
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) { 

     [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

}
```

Furthermore, don't forget to add two keys

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

and

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

into your info.plist.

Leave the values empty to use the default messages or you can customize your own by inputting the values.

Answer (score 3):

In ios 8 Authorization is required as below

```
    NSString * osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([osVersion floatValue]>= 8.0 ) {
    [_CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]; //Requests permission to use location services whenever the app is running. 
// [_CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; //Requests permission to use location services while the app is in the foreground. 
    }
    [_CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And you need to add two keys in the plist

1.NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

2.NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 8 Mapview Current Location fire using

You can set in your .plist file

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your app name Or Other string</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your app name Or Other string</string>
```

And your code side you just implement this

CLLocationManager * locationmanager = [CLLocationManager new];

```
locationmanager.delegate = self;
locationmanager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationmanager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationmanager startUpdatingLocation];    
[locationmanager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

```
location = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
[locationmanager stopUpdatingLocation];
```

}

I am using this my app get perfect current location.