# IOS 8 Map is not working: Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am using Xcode 6.I have some problems when I try to get User current Location using CLLocationManager. Even I added the `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to Info.plist file. And also used `[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]`. Then also I am getting console output as

> 2014-10-15 11:45:15.004 MapIOS8[1916:57908] Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.

Comment: so all you want is, fetch the current location of the user?

Comment: You are clearly calling requestWhenInUse to late... Show your code.

Comment: What I want is ,I want to show the user current Location on map

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CLLocationManager *myManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    myManager.delegate=self;
    
    if([CLLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])
    {
        NSLog(@"Inside This method");
        
       
      [myManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        

       
    }
    
  

    
    MKCoordinateRegion myregion;
    
    myregion.span.latitudeDelta=0.11;
    myregion.span.longitudeDelta=0.11;
    [myMap setRegion:myregion animated:YES];
    
    
}

Comment: You shouldn't enable the "show current location" property until you have had a successful authorization callback to your CLLocationManagerDelegate delegate

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911330/ios-8-mapview-current-location-not-fire

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writting the code in this order?

```
CLLocationManager *YourLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
YourLocationManager.delegate = self;
[YourLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
[YourLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];

yourMapView.delegate = self;
yourMapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
```

Also, to get the user location coordinate, you may have to implement this mapkit delegate method

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    [mapView selectAnnotation:userLocation animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS Simulator try to reset location settings from Settings-> General-> Privacy-> Reset location & privacy. Then call:

```
[LocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

At the first execution must appear a popup to allow the use of the current user's position. After allow the use of current location start your LocationManager with:

```
[LocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```