# Xcode 6.0.1 - iPhone simulator not getting location

Tags: ios-simulator, core-location, xcode6

I've recently updated to xcode 6.0.1. When I run my app on the simulator, neither the

```
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

nor the

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

methods were called. Anybody is seeing this issue? It was working fine in xcode 5.

Getting location update on the device is fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation...the easiest way to look at references is double click the word in question and in the Quick Help tab in the right side bar it will give a description of what can be utilized...

- (void)startUpdatingLocation

notify your delegate by calling its

locationManager:didUpdateLocations method or

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation

Comment: @Michael also verify you have the new calling methods in place...see :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you ticked Allow Location Simulation in the Xcode's Scheme.