# Why dosen't CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation fire in iOS8?

Tags: ios8

I'm an test an existing locations functionality in iOS 8.0 using the simulators that come with XCode 6. I am unable to get [CLLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation) to trigger either [CLLocationManagerDelegate.locationManager:didUpdateLocations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didUpdateLocations:) or 
[CLLocationManagerDelegate.locationManager:didFailWithError](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didFailWithError:).

I don't get the ""My App" Would Like to Use Your Current Location" alert, like I do on the iOS 7.0.3 simulators. I have used the Maps app to verify that the simulated locations set.

This works fine in the iOS 7.0.3 simulators.

Where I'm I going wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS 8 : Location Services not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)

Answer (score 9):

iOS 8 requires that you call either [CLLocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestWhenInUseAuthorization) or [CLLocationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/requestAlwaysAuthorization) before you call `CLLocationManager.startUpdatingLocation`.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

`requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and `requestAlwaysAuthorization` run asynchronously so you want to make sure that your CLLocationManager object isn't cleaned-up before the use can respond to the alert.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
        self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"requestWhenInUseAuthorization");
        if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:selector]) {
            [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        } else {
            [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        }
    } else {
        ...
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    } else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // iOS 7 will redundantly call this line.
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    } else if (status > kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
        ...
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    ...
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    ...
}
```

When you implement `CLLocationManagerDelegate` you now need to implement the [locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:) method as well. Within this method you can check if the user has given the app permission or not, and act accordingly.

**If** `[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] = nil` **then** `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` **will be called when the authorizationStatus is set to** `kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` **and again when the user make their selection from the alert dialog.**

Comment: Adrian do you know how to display the status bar message, when the app is in the background. Google maps does it when the navigation is turned on. “Google Maps is using your Location”

Answer (score 2):

...Also to add to Adrian Toman's answer

Do not forget to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or  `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to you *application-Info.plist* file.

Once you add the property to your plist, you also need to add a string value to it, this string value will be presented to the user when you are asking for their permission to use their location.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)statLocationManager
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; //whenever we move
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; // Add this Line


}
```

And Add following in Info.plist

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adrian Toman's answer if the device is WiFi only try to disable/enable location settings.

Answer (score 0):

I once encountered this problem, when I called `startUpdatingLocation`, `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:` did not get response. Even if I followed all instruction which others provided here, I couldn't get this method triggered.

Finally I realized one thing critical to it was it needed set the delegate of the locationManager to "self" (where you implemented the method `locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:`).

Eventually, everything ran well after that.