# cllocationmanager not asking for user permission ios8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, location, ios8, cllocationmanager

Here is my code :

```
    if (!_locationManager)
    {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [_locationManager setDelegate:self];
    }
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

please help if someone knows.. Thanks

Comment: Go through this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a call to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` when using location services for **iOS-8.0** and above. Find the sample code below.

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationManager.delegate = self;

// this check is required for iOS 8+
// selector 'requestWhenInUseAuthorization' is first introduced in iOS 8
if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}

[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

For more information see this [blog](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Add `[locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];` to your code and add the entry `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your .plist with the value being some sort of message that you want to ask the user for their permission.

Comment: I was missing the .plist entry :)