# locationManager 'didExitRegion' not getting called iBeacon Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibeacon

I'm working with my iBeacon iOS app. I started coding with Xcode 5.1. Ath that time every delegates get called. But while I updated my Xcode to 6.0.1 to support the app in iOS 8, the following delegate method is not getting called (tested in device):

```
-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager 
          didExitRegion:(CLRegion*)region
```

It is workinng perfectly in iOS 7. Can anyone please suggest me any possible solution for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kepp this with your locationmanager instance

```
  self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    // New iOS 8 request for Always Authorization, required for iBeacons to work!
    if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
```

and keep your app background refreshing ON. I am running this in iOS 8 and it is working like a charm.

For more help you can read this article
[iBeacon](http://ibeaconmodules.us/blogs/news/14279747-tutorial-ibeacon-app-development-with-corelocation-on-apple-ios-7-8) http://ibeaconmodules.us/blogs/news/14279747-tutorial-ibeacon-app-development-with-corelocation-on-apple-ios-7-8

Answer (score 2):

On iOS 8, requesting location permissions is a little different. You must request either to allow your app to use location services while your app is being used or always.

For iBeacons to work in the background, you must request to have permissions to always have feedback from Core Location, so always allow location updates.

Comment: Hey Daniel, thx for replying. I've allowed the app to always allow location updates. However it still doesn't work for me...

Comment: Got it! For iOS 8 we need to set the location Manager to request always authorization

Answer (score 1):

Once check

Go to `settings` > `Privacy` > `Location services` > `Your app` > `Always`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the location manager for iOS8:

```
// Needed for iOS 8
if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}
```

Cheers :D