# How to get current location latitude and longitude in IOS SDK 8.0

Tags: ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation, currentlocation

how to get current location latitude and longitude.

I have try this. Using Xcode 6.01 and IOS SDK 8.0

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) getLocation{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
    return coordinate;
}

- (void)getCurrentLocation{    
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self getLocation];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"Latitude  = %@", latitude);
    NSLog(@"Longitude = %@", longitude);
}


- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self getCurrentLocation];

}
```

Here I enable the simulator location to Deployment 8.0 iPhone simulator 4s. 
Even on device its not working.

@ALL
Please let me know, what i have done wrong here.

Answer (score 5):

I figure it out issue in IOS 8.0

**NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**  add this manually into application plist file, leave string value empty.
This it will call the delegate methods.  Never forgot about adding **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**  unless you not added this delegate method will not work. Remaining code is same. with adding delegate methods to controller class.

add this line of code in locationManager declaration code.  for IOS 8.0 
     [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 8, this *code fails silently* i.e you won’t get any error or warning.

You need to do two extra things to get location working:

1. **Add a key to your Info.plist**
2. **Request authorization** from the location manager asking it to start.

Any one or both of below keys needs to be added in Info.plist file.

1. **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**
2. **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**

These are of String type and value can be any message description or empty.

Now you need to request authorisation for corresponding location method. Use any one of below calls :

1. **[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]**
2. **[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the simulator offers an over-simplified rendition of location services. A physical device is the only way to really test `CLLocationManager` behavior.

The issue is that when you call `startUpdatingLocation`, it doesn't mean that you can immediately retrieve the `location`. (I think you'll find it's either `nil` or has a negative `horizontalAccuracy`, which means the location has not yet been determined.)

You must conform to the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`, and implement `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`, which is called asynchronously. So, you have to wait for this method to be called before trying to use the location information. And, note, on a real device, you will likely see this method called a number times as the device refines the device location information, with increasing accuracy (e.g. you may see the `horizontalAccuracy` number dropping from one location update to another).

---

Obviously, you probably want to implement `locationManager:didFailWithError:`, too, so problems can be detected. You probably should also to check `authorizationStatus`, `locationServicesEnabled`, and call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`, before calling `startUpdatingLocation`.

Answer (score 0):

It appears we need to do some more task to implement location services in ios8.
[follow this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)

Comment: added both delegate method didFailWithError and didUpdateToLocation but this methods are not triggering at all

Comment: please add CLLocationManagerDelegate in your .h file like this    @interface DemoViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>

Comment: I added CLLocationManagerDelegate, still i have issue.  there is something wrong after upgrade sdk IOS 7 to IOS 8.