# iOS Location Services auto unselects on iOS8

Tags: ios, ios7, gps, location, ios8

I'm developing an app which uses GPS tracking.
My application was working well until my boss upgraded his device to iOS 8.0.2

In "Settings > Privacy > Location Services > MyApp" even after I choose "Always", it will forget this setting on iOS8.

On the simulator I have the same issue, but when I choose "Always" then go back to the app it starts working. This does not seem to happen on the iPhone.

Has anyone encountered this issue?

In iOS8 it does not prompt me: "MyApp would like to use your current location ... Don't Allow | Ok" ... but in iOS7 it does. Is this an OS bug? Is there a different solution?

thanks

Comment: Found some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working