# Why does my PhoneGap/Cordova app's Location Services privacy setting disappear?

Tags: ios, cordova, core-location

I am preparing my PhoneGap/Cordova-based app for use on iOS 8. I am using Xcode 6 and PhoneGap/Cordova 3.6.3. My app requires location services permission.

iOS 8 is not storing or maintaining state on the location services. In fact, it's not asking the user for permission to access location services.

If you go to Settings>Privacy>Location>Bike Guide, you'll see that no setting is checked. If you check "Always" and leave Settings.app to enter Bike Guide.app, the setting is quickly lost (see screenshot) and Bike Guide.app cannot get the device's location.

How do you fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you update to the last available version? There are some issues resolved https://github.com/weili-feedhenry/cordova-plugin-geolocation/commit/4b88fea0d5de3971358913d18e47aae6873e9f2e

Comment: This solve the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working