# CLLocationManager delegate not called

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I am using iBeacons, but am running into a small problem.

On first use the user needs to give permission, we then following is called:

```
_locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
_locationManager.delegate = self;
[_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

However, I expected the following delegate method to be called:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    NSLog(@"Auth status changed: %i", status);
    if(status > 3){
        // Check if we have to start monitoring beacons
        NSLog(@"Do we need to initialise after auth given?");
        //[self initialiseLocations];
    }
}
```

I am running iOS 8.0.2, so not sure if this is a bug

Comment: Did you set a strong reference to locationManager, something like `@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocationManager *locationManager;`?

Comment: No, but have it declared in the .h file, so globally. The containing class is strong, defined in the appDelegate. All other callbacks work fine, just this one.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24063578/1457357) might help... it solved it for me at least. Also [this website](http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/getting-gps-location-using-core-location-in-ios-8-vs-ios-7/) was a good walkthrough for this issue as well.

It looks like you are calling the requestAlwaysAuthorization correctly, but do you call `startUpdatingLocation` anywhere? Also, double check that in your *Info.plist* you have the appropriate key and string value added (`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` since you're using `requestAlwaysAuthorization`).

Comment: I have those set, and it works fine otherwise (I use it for iBeacons, so don't need to start startUpdatingLocation, as that is for GPS). That is why I need the callback, so I can initiate the request to track the beacons.

Comment: Oh, I've never used iBeacons so I'm not entirely sure then... I did a quick search however and found [this tutorial](http://ibeaconmodules.us/blogs/news/14279747-tutorial-ibeacon-app-development-with-corelocation-on-apple-ios-7-8) over using them and it states that they made edits to it to work with iOS 8 so maybe it will help?