# iOS8 CLLocationManager not working after applying updates

Tags: ios8, cllocationmanager

Like everyone else when they upgraded to iOS8 their CLLocationManager apps began to not work. I have read around the subject and think I have applied the fixes but the locationManager is still not being called. I have clearly missed something out....

```
#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
    if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
        [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        NSLog(@"iOS8");        
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; }
```

Comment: You could find an answer [on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally it appears you need to add one or both string entries to plist.info. Without these you won't get any errors and it just won't work period.

NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

And hey presto everything will work. There is a very good explanation at

http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/