# Strange text in info.plist what should the correct text be

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I noticed somehow I had stack overflow data in my plist ... must have pasted it or something once back in the day.  Any idea what is supposed to actually go here?

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>I have learned more on stack overflow than anything else</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>The spirit of stack overflow is coders helping coders</string>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You tried to fix location services on iOS 8 and copied the solution [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24064860/104790). Note: While your trust in SO is appreciated it's generally a good idea to at least understand what you are copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These keys are for showing the location usage information (iOS 8 and 8+).
In your app if you are using location services the corresponding text will be shown, when it asks for location permission.

You need to add the reason, for which you need the location service permission.

Check this [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)