# iOS 8 requestWhenInUseAuthorization: no popup in appstore version

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager

I updated my app for the iOS 8 location services with the requestWhenInUseAuthorization/NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription solution.
( [Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working/24063578#24063578) )

on iOS 8: It is working well if I run the app from Xcode (I get the popup); but it doesn't work (no popup; no location retrieved) if I run the version I download from the apple-store.

Has anyone an idea why ?

Comment: Have you added the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in your info.plist ?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8.0.2 doesn't ask *if* the user had given permission before.  Even if the app was deleted and reinstalled, it remembers that permission was once given and doesn't ask again. I tested our app in several phones and that what I discovered.

Comment: Very weird. Are you sure about this? Until iOS7, when you deleted the app, you where being asked immediately for permissions again after re-installing it. Only Push Notification permission would be remembered. Weird!

Comment: That's what I found when testing.  After deleting it wouldn't ask.  As soon it was reinstalled, even before running it, you can see the permissions in the Settings app are already granted!  I tried 3 devices and on each one it would prompt on the first run, but then never again.  That was iOS 8.0.2, perhaps its a bug, I haven't tried it on 8.1 yet.

Comment: I didn't observe that on 8.1; but my problem is not only that it doesn't ask: it doesn't receive positions either.