# Error in ios 8 for current location

Tags: ios8

I am using this code for current location in ios 8, but this give the error on 3rd line 
error is "no known class method for selector' requestAlwaysAuthorization".

```
  if ([CLLocationManager respondsToSelector:
       @selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
      [CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
   }
```

Comment: http://matthewfecher.com/app-developement/getting-gps-location-using-core-location-in-ios-8-vs-ios-7/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/ios-8-location-services-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 8 SDK, **requestAlwaysAuthorization** (for background location) or **requestWhenInUseAuthorization** (location only when foreground) call on CLLocationManager is needed before starting location updates.

Add two keys in the plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message goes here</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message goes here</string>
```

(Leave the values empty to use the default messages)