# iBeacon not working in ad hoc distributed app

Tags: ios, ibeacon, ad-hoc-distribution

I built and tested an iBeacon enabled app using my dev environment. When it comes time to distribute it to beta testers/sales colleagues, the app does not seem to do any ranging/monitoring anymore. I am using a wildcard profile and am able to export the archive, but it just does not seem to work. Do I have to get a different certificate or a certificate that's not a wildcard one?

Comment: There might be issues with permissions. Often happens.

Comment: Remove the app. restart the phone and add the app again

Comment: Sometimes it happens that app is not registered for the use of location services, and it happens even if the app has those permissions, instal/re-install and it may help.

Comment: Hi thomi, have you found the solution for this? we too facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, as I posted in my answer, There are some specialities that need to be configured in ios8 deployment, which can also be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8) helped getting it to work on a new iPhone 6. I'll test and add a comment when finished

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I needed to add all the location permissions items required for iOS 8 to the app's info.plist.