# Location Manager in IOS 8 Not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I tried displaying the current location of the user (I mainly need the zip code,) and nothing happens when I launch the app, the app just displays empty labels without a crash message.
Here is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
}

@synthesize array, mytableView, latitudeLabel, longitudeLabel, addressLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8) {
        [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

    // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            addressLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}

- (IBAction)getCurrentLocation:(id)sender {
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
```

Comment: Have you set your plist to allow for location authorization?

Comment: I don't have anything in a plist, so im not using it.

Comment: You need to update your plist: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24063578/2274694

Comment: It gave me the longitude and the latitude, but t did not give me the address. Is that because it's running on the simulator and not an actual device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these properties in your plist file. The value of string could be anything you want.

[image]

**Edited to  further answer another query of Mike in the comment:**

In your viewcontroller's .h file

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

Comment: I get this error by locationManager.delegate = self; saying "Assigning 'id<CLLocationManagerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const_strong'" 1-What does that mean, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think you haven't registered the view controller in which you are trying to get locatioin as Locations manager's delegate. Implement <CLLocationManagerDelegate> protocol in your viewcontroller.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but today when I tested out my app it gave me the error of Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"