# Swift, CLLocationManagerDelegate in NSObject not working

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

i have problem with getting my location with CLLocationDelegate.
i created new subclass of UIView and work well, but when i created subclass of NSObject, CLLocationDelegate not called. I can find where is problem.
here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class LocationData: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

override init() {
    super.init()
    if self.locationManager.respondsToSelector(Selector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    println("init LocationData")
}

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(error.description)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!) {
    println("updated")
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine! But when instantiating the class, you need to do like this:

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

 let LocationData: LocationData = LocationData()  //<- here is the secret to works!!!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

I also suggest that you change your `init` to something like this:

```
override init() {
    super.init()

    let authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    if authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    print("init LocationData")
}
```

And don't forget to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in the `info.plist` project.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day!