# Objective-C: Finding User Location (Not on a Map)

Tags: ios, objective-c, null, geolocation, core-location

I am trying to make my app find a user's location in an address-like form (located after the "Reverse Geocoding" comment).  Below is my code:

```
- (IBAction)getuserlocation:(id) sender{
    //Getting Location
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(address);
}
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }

    // Stop Location Manager
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];

}
```

My issue is that the compiler only prints out "(null)".  (The line where I do this is located in the "getuserlocation" IBAction.)  I'm not sure why this is.  I've tested the app on an actual iPhone 6 Plus, which unlike the simulator, has access to location services.

If anyone would be able to point out where the error/problem in my code is, causing it to print out null, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thanks in advance to all who reply.

***BTW: The following lines are in my viewDidLoad section:
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

Comment: FYI - It's not the compiler that logs anything. It's your running app that is logging the message.

Comment: Ok.  That is what I meant to type.  Sorry for any confusion this may have caused.

Comment: In addition to accessing the address variable before you have set a value, you need to make sure you have put the appropriate reason string in your info.plist and called `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` .  You are also using a deprecated location delegate method.  You should use `didUpdateLocations:`.  Finally, disabling location updates after you receive the first location isn't a good idea as the first location probably won't be very accurate.  You should continue to receive updates, perhaps waiting for a low value in the `horizonalAccuracy` property of the `CLLocation`

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your quick reply!  I am fairly new to Objective-C programming so where exactly would I put this in my info.plist file?  I don't see a reason string option anywhere in this file.  Also, how do I have my app request permission to receive access to the user's current location?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8/24063578#24063578

Answer (score 0):

You are logging `address` long before you get a location and convert it to an address.

Move the `NSLog(address);` to just after where you actually assign a value to `address`.

BTW - it should be more like: `NSLog(@"Address: %@, address);`.

Comment: Ok.  So how can I access address from the methods before assigning the values to them if I need to use it in my IBAction?  Thank you for the reply by the way. :)

Comment: I tried moving the NSLog like you told me, but nothing ever logged to the console.  Is this code not being reached?

Comment: Are you getting any of the other log messages in your code? Does you app have permission to use location services? Did you setup your location manager to request permission?

Comment: I am not getting other logs in my console either.  Also, I'm not sure how to request permission to get location.  Could this be my problem?  I couldn't find out how to do this online.

Comment: I did and added the lines @paulw11 said I should, yet it is still not getting my location.  Not sure what to do.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code and details about how you have setup your location manager.