# background location not working in enterprise builds

Tags: ios, core-location, provisioning-profile

I have an app that uses `CLLocationManager` while running in the background.  It works fine on a device when built using my development certificate, but when I build it for release using the enterprise certificate, location doesn't run in the background.

I don't see any difference between the Debug build and the Release build that could cause this.  I've checked the plist of the enterprise build's .ipa file and it has the location key for required background mode.

Is there some entitlement required that maybe isn't in the enterprise profile?

Comment: Are you putting the enterprise build on the same device that the dev build was deployed to?

Comment: Initially it was a different device, but when it didn't work right, I tried it on the first device and it had the same problem.

Comment: I was hoping it was a Location services permission issue. :/

Comment: I checked to make sure it had "Always" permissions in the Settings app.

Comment: location works as long as the app is in the foreground, it stops when it goes to the background.

Comment: aha, its somehow caused by the Release build, not because its an enterprise build.  i tried building a Debug enterprise build and it worked fine in the background.

Comment: I found this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8