# Filter out bad locations from CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation, cllocationdistance

I find that often while using CLLocationManager:

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;
```

and it's delegate method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;
```

I will get results that look like the below, even while not moving at all. I know the location service is not always 100% accurate and is subject to network conditions, but is there some way to filter out bad locations so that I don't end up with random stray points like this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's weird. We almost have the same code and mine's working. Did you execute `[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` once?

Also try adding `[self.locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`. I will switch to that and do some testing.

Comment: I tried switching to `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, but then I get no location updates at all. Do you have to do anything else to get iOS to think a location change is significant?

Comment: this is my code for initializing my locationManager  


`- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager`
`{`
    `if (!_locationManager) {`
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        if ([_locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
            [_locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        }
        [_locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
    return _locationManager;
}

Comment: also check this link for iOS 8 location services 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8