# CLLocation manager not working iOS 8

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I'm trying to follow this Google Maps tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/81103/introduction-google-maps-ios-sdk-swift

Like many others I have hit a roadblock where `CLLocationManager` does not seem to fire `startUpdatingLocation()`.

I have updated the `pList` with `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in accordance with [Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8), but still no location being fired.

Code below - any help is appreciated!

```
import UIKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, TypesTableViewControllerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mapCenterPinImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pinImageVerticalConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var searchedTypes = ["bakery", "bar", "cafe", "grocery_or_supermarket", "restaurant"]
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Types Segue" {
            let navigationController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController.topViewController as TypesTableViewController
            controller.selectedTypes = searchedTypes
            controller.delegate = self
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Types Controller Delegate
    func typesController(controller: TypesTableViewController, didSelectTypes types: [String]) {
        searchedTypes = sorted(controller.selectedTypes)
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        if status == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            println("success") // Works
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() // Does not seem to fire

            mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
            mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("test") // Does not work
        println(locations.count) // Does not work

        if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {

            mapView.camera = GMSCameraPosition(target: location.coordinate, zoom: 15, bearing: 0, viewingAngle: 0)

            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8?lq=1

Comment: Hernant  - agreed. This is why I refer to it in the Question. Code is fine, but issue is that you have to change where you simulate your location for `didUpdateLocations` to fire. Which is not mentioned in the referred Question.

Others might face same issue - to avoid that - I would keep the question open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unbelievable. After a day of testing I found the solution.. Code is fine. **Simulation requires that you change the location**

Steps:

1. In Xcode Simulator --> Debug --> Location --> Apple (or whatever..)
2. Re-run simulation

Google Map will now be centered on where you chose
    in your simulation settings (Xcode --> Edit Scheme --> Allow
    Simulation + Default Location = New York)

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

The code seems okay also you have mentioned that you have updated info.plist. Can you check with "requestAlwaysAuthorization" instead of "requestWhenInUseAuthorization". Hope it may solve your problem.

You can also refer this link - http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/

Comment: This would be more helpful to others with this problem if you would add some explanation of what to do with this code snippet and how it will fix the problem.