# Trying to send POST parameters with latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager

I am trying to send some parameters to my phpMyAdmin tables that contains a filed called latitude and longitude. Since then, i need to obtain the device coordinates and transform them into a string.

I have followed the Ray Wenderlich tutorial but i am still getting "nil" in my parameters. Take a look at the following code:

1 - I have added the framework to the code and imported the CoreLocation files to my "ResumeView.h", also, declared both latitude and longitude Strings.

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ResumeView : GAITrackedViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
NSString *latitude;
NSString *longitude;
```

2 - Now, on my "ResumeView.m" i've add the rest of the code as followed by the tutorial...

```
@implementation ResumeView {

    CLLocationManager *manager;

}

@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize longitude;
```

3 - Now, on viewDidLoad...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    manager.delegate = self;

    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

4 - Then, these functions were introduced along my code, of course, before the POST parameters could be sent.

```
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDellegate Methods

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *) manager didFailWithError: (NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    NSLog(@"Failed to get location! :(");
}

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSLog(@"Location: %@", newLocation);

    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
        longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
    }
}
```

5 - And here is where the problem makes comes, both coordinate values are "nil"and cannot be sent to the database.

```
 @"latitude":latitude, // <---- error here! is nil when sending to database!
 @"longitude":longitude, // <---- error here! is nil when sending to database!
```

Comment: Did you check that your current location is not nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are nil because the location manager never sends you updates. There's new functions you need to call in iOS 8 to get the location manager to work. See this post as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24063578/78496