# MKMapView won't show user location

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mkmapview

I have 2 apps that use MKMapViews and they both previously worked fine, but now they won't show the user's location. Can anyone think of a reason this code wouldn't make a map show the user's blue dot?

```
mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
mapView.delegate = self;
```

I really appreciate any help, I'm stumped right now...

Comment: Hi. Are your apps requests the permission from user (about location) when showing the controller with map?

Comment: I thought the OS did that automatically when you try to access the user's location. This code has worked fine in the past, but suddenly stopped. What would I have to do to make my app request permission?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8