# Why requestWhenInUseAuthorization doesn't prompt the user for access to the location?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8, cllocationmanager

In my `viewDidLoad` method I have

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; // initializing locationManager
locationManager.delegate = self; // we set the delegate of locationManager to self.
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];


if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
```

And the request is called, but the user is not prompted? Why?

Comment: Also, checking the OS version the way you're doing isn't recommended. Better to use `if([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization:)])`

Answer (score 295, accepted):

You probably need to update your `plist` file. Here's a [tutorial how to do it](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/), quick & dirty:

You need to do is to add one of the following keys to your Info.plist file:

```
NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
```

You also need to request authorization for the corresponding location method, `WhenInUse` or `Background`. Use one of these calls:

```
[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]
```

There's also a post that I found helpful:

[Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8)

This answer details [how to update your `plist` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24064860/4475605):

> Add one of the following lines to your info.plist
>
> ```xml
> <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
> <string>The spirit of stack overflow is coders helping coders</string>
>
> <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
> <string>I have learned more on stack overflow than anything else</string>
> ```

You'll probably want to customize and spell-check the strings of the dictionary entry that goes in the info.plist file before [shipping the code](https://twitter.com/Scott_Helme/status/727832672551219201).