# iphone: didUpdateLocations not invoked when testing with the simulator

Tags: ios-simulator, ios9, cllocationmanager

When debugging my app with the simulator, the routine didUpdateLocations is never involved. What I do:

In the simulator, I select Debug>location>Custom Location and the window with longitude and latitude pops up. When pressing ok, I would expect the didUpdateLocations to be called.

I use locMgr as a global variable in a ViewController-module:

```
locMgr = CLLocationManager()
```

and in the viewDidLoad-function includes the following sequence:

```
    locMgr.delegate = self
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
        locMgr.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
```

I have coded the didUpdateLocations-function as a method of my viewcontroller class. I also verified (debugger), that the requestWhenInUseAuthorization-routine is invoked during initialisation. So were is the problem, why is the didUpdateLocations protocol-routine not invoked?

Comment: I find, that even after the call to requestWhenInUseAuthorization() the status is unchanged and is still .NotDetermined

Comment: Have you added the two keys to you Info.plist as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31845567/498796)?

Comment: Instead of running my app in the simulator, I downloaded it to my iPhone. Same behaviour. didUpdateLocations is not invoked.

Comment: Yes - it was the Info.plist file entry that was missing. Thank you dasdom and shame on Apple. The fact that this entry is required in Info.plist is dammed well hidden....

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post it as an answer because it is to trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dasdom solved the problem by suggesting: [Why requestWhenInUseAuthorization doesn't prompt the user for access to the location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31845450/why-requestwheninuseauthorization-doesnt-prompt-the-user-for-access-to-the-loca/31845567#31845567)