# Location Fetching Error Ios

Tags: ios

My app that works fine on iOS 7 doesn't work with the iOS 8 SDK.

**CLLocationManager** doesn't return a location, and I don't see my app under `Settings -> Location Services` either. I did a Google search on the issue, but nothing came up. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you requesting permission and have you put the appropriate key into your info.plist? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8

Comment: No i haven't put key in info.plist.

Answer (score 0):

Add below in your `info.plist`

Key: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` type: `String` value:prompt message eg- Requires your current location

Answer (score 0):

in ios 8+ u need to request permission `[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]` for only us3 when in app and `[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]` for always use location

this code perfectly work on ios 8

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)startSignificantChangeUpdates
{
    if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        if (!self.locationManager)
           self.locationManager =  [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];


        self.locationManager.delegate = self;

        // request location when app in use
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}



- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
   [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    CLGeocoder * geoCoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    for (CLPlacemark * placemark in placemarks) {
        NSString *country = placemark.ISOcountryCode;
        cityName = [placemark locality];
    }
    }];
}
```