# Core Location to an iOS Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, core-location, cllocationmanager

I am creating an iOS Framework and i want to use Core Location to interact with Beacons. For testing reasons i am trying to get user location.

This is the class i created in the framework.

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

 public class BeaconManager:NSObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    public override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

     public func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {
            println(location)
        }
    }
}
```

And i am calling it from a test app that has the framework like this

```
import UIKit
import OtravitaSDK
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

      var bm = BeaconManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

But is not working , is not printing the location. **I have set the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription both in framework's info.plist and the app's info.plist**

Comment: Do you get the request to allow location access?

Comment: No i dont. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add your decription in `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` & `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` in plist

This code put into `AppDelegate` file

```
     var locationManager:CLLocationManager?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

      //You can give this permission for fetch current location
        var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
        var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil);
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting);
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications();

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {
        if let location = locations.first as? CLLocation {
            println(location)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do as of iOS 8 is configure your `Info.plist file` to cater for 2 kinds of location behaviour. You need to supply a default message that appears with a popup by default, asking the user for consent to use their location.

`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

See [this article](http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/) for a full walkthrough and [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8) which discusses this topic. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create at first the reporter class (with shared instance) which will implement the CLLocationManagerDelegate, so you could implement your logic inside delegate methods

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationReporter: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance = LocationReporter()

    func startUpdating(locationManager: CLLocationManager) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func stopUpdating(locationManager: CLLocationManager) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            print("latitude: ", location.coordinate.latitude)
            print("longitude: ", location.coordinate.longitude)
        }
    }

  //implement other locationManger delegate methods


}
```

Next you can create a Client class

```
 import Foundation
 import CoreLocation

 class LocationDetectionClient {

    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func start() {
        LocationReporter.sharedInstance.startUpdating(locationManager: locationManager)
    }

    func stop() {
        LocationReporter.sharedInstance.stopUpdating(locationManager: locationManager)
    }

}
```

And finally call the Client methods where you need

```
let locationDetectionClient = LocationDetectionClient()

public func startLocationDetection() {
    locationDetectionClient.start()
}

public func stopLocationDetection() {
    locationDetectionClient.stop()
}
```

Hope this would help