# How to wait for the result of an async function in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have written the following function to find out the placemark of an image. This also works, because if a url of an image with the appropriate metadata is given the correct placemark is returned.

```swift
func GetLocationFromFoto(url: URL, completion: @escaping ([CLPlacemark]?) -> Void) {
    guard let con = getImageMetadata(imageURL: url)?["{GPS}"] as? NSDictionary else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    
    if let lat = con["Latitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees, let lon = con["Longitude"] as? CLLocationDegrees {
        let loc = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc) { placemarks, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Geocoding error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            let country = placemarks
            completion(country)
        }
    } else {
        completion(nil)
    }
}
```

Since the function `geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc)` runs async, I used a completion. But now it disturbs the further flow of the program. So is there a possibility that the main function waits for this async function and then has a simple return value? The head of the function should look like this: `func GetLocationFromFoto(url: URL) -> [CLPlacemark]? {`

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you aware of Swift's Concurrency features? i.e. `async` and `await`. Your function could be `func GetLocationFromFoto(url: URL) async throws -> [CLPlacemark]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this link to getting the latitude and longitude [Core Location to an iOS Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604687/core-location-to-an-ios-framework). As per your justification you need to wait for the geocoding function then you want to execute your code. So, I just simply print the "Hello" and the "World" separately so first "Hello" prints and then it waits for the function to complete and then it prints "World".

```
import Foundation
import CoreLocation

class LocationReporter: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    static let sharedInstance = LocationReporter()

    func startUpdating(locationManager: CLLocationManager) {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func stopUpdating(locationManager: CLLocationManager) {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let location = locations.first {
            let lati = location.coordinate.latitude
            let longi = location.coordinate.longitude
            
            print("latitude: ", location.coordinate.latitude)
            print("longitude: ", location.coordinate.longitude)
            Task {
                print("Hello")
                await GetLocationFromFoto(latitude:lati, longitude:longi)
                print("World")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func GetLocationFromFoto(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) async {
        let lat = latitude
        let lon = longitude
        let loc = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        do {
            let country = try await geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(loc)
            for data in country {
                print(data.country)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print("Geocoding error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```