# How do i get QGeoPositionInfoSource to emit a signal in Qt 5.5.1 with iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I would appreciate if anybody can help me with this (did not find anything relevant with Google).

I am trying to get positioning info in iOS using Qt. Have tried the simulator as well as a real iPhone. I get at source from QGeoPositionInfoSource that says "corelocation", but source does not seem to emit a signal since positionUpdated never gets called. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

`MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QGeoPositionInfoSource *source = QGeoPositionInfoSource::createDefaultSource(this);
    if (source){
        connect(source, SIGNAL(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)),this, SLOT(positionUpdated(QGeoPositionInfo)));
        source->setUpdateInterval(100);
        source->startUpdates();
        qDebug()<<"Source found";
        qDebug()<<source->availableSources();
    }else{
        qDebug()<<"Failed source";
    }
}

void MainWindow::positionUpdated(const QGeoPositionInfo &info)
   {
        qDebug() << "Position updated:" << info;
   }`

UPDATE-----------------------------
Getting the error from source says "An unidentified error occurred.". Not very helpful but at least its not an issue related to lacking privileges (error 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post solved my problem. You have to edit the info.plist file (from xcode or with a text editor).

[Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8)