# Error when getting user location with CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I am using a collection view and collection view reusable header. In the header, i am trying to get the user's location. I keep getting this error:

```
   Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for    
   location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager    
   requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager    
   requestAlwaysAuthorization] first.
```

I looked at this question: [Location Services not working in iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062509/location-services-not-working-in-ios-8)  and none of the proposed solutions worked for me. I have added the keys (both NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription) to my info.Plist and that did not help. The app never requests the user to get it's location. Here is my code:

EDIT: my code now:

```
   import UIKit
   import MapKit
   import Parse
   import ParseUI
   import CoreLocation

   class ReusableHeaderMap: UICollectionReusableView, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

@IBOutlet weak var newMap: MKMapView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied {

    }
    else if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    else if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else {
        print("it took the else route")

    }

    print("status is \(status)")
    self.newMap.layer.cornerRadius = 8
    self.newMap.clipsToBounds = true

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if locations.count > 0 {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        let location1 = locations.first as CLLocation!
        let mapSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
        let mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location1.coordinate, span: mapSpan)
        self.newMap.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)
    }
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.Denied {
        print("there will be limited functionaliy")
    }
    else if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedAlways {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    else {
        print("it took the else route")
      }
   }


}
```

my info.plist has this key:

```
  <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Get User Location</string>
```

Comment: I assume that you are testing on the device. delete the app from the device and try it again.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work, I still receive the same error message.

Comment: What value are you getting back from `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()`? And is your `didChangeAuthorizationStatus()` method being called?

Comment: the status is NotDetermined. And yes, the didCHangeAuthorizationStatus() is being called. in there, I have "else if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }", but it never gives a prompt to the user to ask for authorization.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you what you have to do. You need to make a call to

```
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

or

```
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

In your code before you attempt to start up the location manager. That step is in addition to adding the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and/or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` keys to info.plist.

See the docs on those methods for more information.

(Looking at the code you posted, you aren't setting things up correctly. You can't just call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` and then `startUpdatingLocation` immediately after.)

As the docs say:

> When the current authorization status is
>   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined, this method runs **asynchronously**
>   and prompts the user to grant permission to the app to use location
>   services.

The key word there is *asynchronously*.

You need to make that call, then implement the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` method. That method (didChangeAuthorizationStatus) will be called if the user grants your app permission to use location services.

Your code should look more like this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() 
{
  locationManager.delegate = self
  let status = locationManager.status
  if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)
  {
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  }
  else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
  {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
  }
  else
  {
    //Handle other error cases here.
  }
  newMap.layer.cornerRadius = 8
  newMap.clipsToBounds = true
}

optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
  didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
{
  locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Comment: I implemented locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus, and inside there put: self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation(). But that still doesn't work, and I still get the same error message in the console. I am running Swift 2 and Xcode 7.0, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't work. i edited my code in my question. (the syntax changed, "locationManager.status" isn't valid in swift2 now, but I think what I have should do the same thing)